# Fill doctrine form with dynamic form elements

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I'm currently working on a Symfony2 project and I'm stuck with the form creation. I have the following setup:

```
<?php
class Field {
private $name;
private $label;
private $type;
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Option", mappedBy="field")
 */
private $options;

....
?>
```

and

```
<?php
class Option {
private $value;
private $type;
/**
 * @var string
 * 
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Field", inversedBy="options")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="field", referencedColumnName="name")
 */
private $field;

....
?>
```

Now, what I'd like to do, I'm creating a form, with the 'field' as a dropdown/option list/radiobutton/checkbox group (which is specified by the Field::$type) and fill the field with it's options. Any ideas?

Edit: What could be important: I don't need the ability to add, remove or change the options. They are fix in the database and just need to be chosen from. Some with the mulitple, some without.

Edit2: Just to clarify: I'm building my forms with Symfony Forms: I have a basic form type ("Case") which contains the Fields which contain its Options:

```
class CaseType extends AbstractType
{
    private $case;
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $this->case = $options['data'];
        $builder
            ->add('user')
            ->add('fields', 'collection', array('type' => new FieldType()))
        ;
```

and:

```
class FieldType extends AbstractType
{

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder->add('options', 'entity', array(
                    "class"     => "MyBundle:Option",
                    "property"  => "value",
                    "query_builder" => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                        return $er->createQueryBuilder('o', 'Option')
                            ->where('o.field = :f')
                            ->setParameter('f', **type_of_current_field**)
                            ->orderBy('o.value', "ASC");
                    }
        ));
```

Just this does not work as expected... First because I cannot access the field->type and second it's quite a mess

Edit3: Okay, I absolutely don't get why this does not work:

```
class FieldType extends AbstractType
{

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $formFactory = $builder->getFormFactory();
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) use ($formFactory) {
            $form = $event->getForm();
            $data = $event->getData();

            $form->add('options', 'entity', array(
                    "class"     => "MyBundle:Option",
                    "property"  => "value",
                    "multiple"  => "true",
            ));
        });
```

...
?>

This just gives my the following error:
    Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Shouldn't I be able to just parse out all of the options for one field? Or is my approach completely wrong and I should do it different? When I dump out my fields it looks like this:

```
Field {#427 ▼
  -id: 26
  -name: "MyField"
  -label: "field to fill out"
  -type: "D"
  -public: 1
  -options: PersistentCollection {#440 ▼
    -snapshot: array:2 [ …2]
    -owner: Field {#427}
    -association: array:15 [ …15]
    -em: EntityManager {#289 …10}
    -backRefFieldName: "field"
    -typeClass: ClassMetadata {#401 …}
    -isDirty: false
    -initialized: true
    -coll: ArrayCollection {#397 ▼
      -_elements: array:2 [▼
        0 => Option {#435 ▼
          -id: 91
          -value: 1
          -field: Field {#427}
          -type: "D"
        }
        1 => Option {#432 ▼
          -id: 92
          -value: 2
          -field: Field {#427}
          -type: "D"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: do you use twig engine for templating?

Comment: I use doctrine and twig

Comment: Have you thought about using [Symfony forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html)?

Comment: I'm already using forms, but I didn't find anything (or I'm just too blind) about cascading over multiple tables. This here helped me a bit: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html but not all the way...

Answer (score 0):

Pretty basic example you can extend.

```
{% for f in fields %}
    {% if f.type == 'select' %}
        <select>
        {% for o in f.options %}
              <option value="{{ o.value }}">{{ o.value }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
        </select>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The problem was, that Doctrine <2.5 does load all the Options automatically when loading the Fields. So I managed to create a workaround:

```
$formFactory = $builder->getFormFactory();
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) use ($formFactory) {
            $form = $event->getForm();
            $this->field = $event->getData();

            $form->add('options', 'entity', array(
                    "class"     => "MyBundle:Option",
                    "property"  => "value",
                    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                        return $er->createQueryBuilder('o')
                            ->where('o.field = :field')
                            ->setParameter('field', $this->field->getName())
                            ->orderBy('o.value', 'ASC');
                    },
            ));
        });
```

The more proper solution would have been to wait for Doctrine 2.5 and then just use the new ability they provide: fetch="EAGER" for OneToMany-Relationships, but it works this way.